# Trying connect to DriveHq ftp client and upload the file

Tags: java, sockets, ftp, ftp-client

My code is for connecting to drivehq ftp client is

```
FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
public boolean upload(File file){
         client.enterLocalPassiveMode();
            client.connect("ftp.drivehq.com");

            client.login("username", "password");
            client.enterLocalPassiveMode();

             fis = new FileInputStream(file);

             status= client.storeFile(" /c/"+file.getName(), fis);

             client.logout();
             fis.close();

}
```

and the error message i'm getting is

```
 java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:194)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:273)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:334)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:254)
        at org.apache.commons.net.telnet.TelnetInputStream.__read(TelnetInputStream.java:114)
        at org.apache.commons.net.telnet.TelnetInputStream.run(TelnetInputStream.java:535)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

I have seen this code is working in one video in sep-2014 but now it's not working?

Comment: Did you check if you can use login to upload files to the corresponding FTP server using a plain ftp client? Are you sure that your credentials are OK?

Comment: yes @EddyG with my  credentials i'm getting lo-ginned

Comment: Then the next step would be: where is the FTPClient implementation coming from; and for example; what does its javadoc say about the parameters for the storeFile() method?

Comment: @EddyG storFile() method parameters are correct only here the error occurs at client.connect("ftp.drivehq.com"); statement.

Comment: Are you sure you provided the full stack trace? And - I assume you are using Apache Commons FTPClient? What version are you using? The other suggestion I would have: setup a ftp server on your own system - to see if you can connect to that one.

Comment: @EddyG yeah the full stack trace i have provided yea the latest version of   commons.net jar i'm using link http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/a/Downloadapachecommonsnetjar.htm

Comment: It can't be the full stack trace - as it doesnt show WHERE inside your upload function the exception is thrown!

Comment: thanks for helping @EddyG i'm using e.printStackTrace(); method for printing full stack trace

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72552/discussion-between-mahender-reddy-yasa-and-eddyg).

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the FTPClient class, but it seems the following line is incorrect:

```
 client.storeFile(" /c/"+file.getName(), fis)
```

Please test a simple path with the file name only first.